# SignatureDoesNotMatch Aws CloudSearch scala

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-cloudsearch

I keep getting:

> "#SignatureDoesNotMatch","error":{"message":"[*Deprecated*: Use the
>   outer message field] The request signature we calculated does not
>   match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and
>   signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

from trying to do a get request to cloudsearch.  I verified that my Canonical String and String-to-Sign match the ones sent back from the error message everytime now, but I keep getting the error.  Im assuming my signature itself isn't being processed correctly.  But hard to nail it down.

```
  def getHash(key:Array[Byte]): String = {
    try
    {
      val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(key)
      md.map("%02x".format(_)).mkString.toLowerCase()
    }
    catch
      {
        case e: Exception => ""
      }
  }
```

.

```
   def HmacSHA256(data:String, key:Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] =  {
    val algorithm="HmacSHA256";
    val mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
    mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
   }
```

.

```
...
val algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
val credential_scope = date + "/us-west-1/cloudsearch/aws4_request"

val string_to_sign = algorithm + "\n" +  dateTime + "\n" +  credential_scope + "\n" +  getHash(canonical_request)


val kSecret = ("AWS4" + config.getString("cloud.secret")).getBytes("utf-8")
val kDate = HmacSHA256(date.toString, kSecret)
val kRegion = HmacSHA256("us-west-1",kDate)
val kService = HmacSHA256("cloudsearch",kRegion)
val kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request",kService)
val signing_key = kSigning
val signature = getHash(HmacSHA256(string_to_sign, kSigning))

val authorization_header = algorithm + " " + "Credential=" + config.getString("cloud.key") + "/" + credential_scope + ", " +  "SignedHeaders=" + signed_headers + ", " + "Signature=" + signature

val complexHolder = holder.withHeaders(("x-amz-date",dateTime.toString))
.withHeaders(("Authorization",authorization_header))
.withRequestTimeout(5000)
.get()
val response = Await.result(complexHolder, 10 second)
```

Comment: Check the time on your server(or wherever you're running the code). If the clock has drifted too much it can cause the signature you generate to be incorrect.

Comment: the times appeared to be same. Was getting time too early or late before, but I fixed it since I wasn't using UTC.  Now they are showing very close times if not same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just released a helper library to sign your HTTP requests to AWS: https://github.com/ticofab/aws-request-signer . Hope it helps!

Comment: I am definitely going to look into your stuff. Can you provide a snippet of something here for those that don't want to traipse off to a different site? Thanks

Comment: Thanks thats just what I was looking for.

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty, have you used it? any feedback?